# Stop stored procedure from running for all errors except ORA-00942 table does not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure in Oracle 11g that will delete records for specific clients in some tables.  The below script is an example of its set up.  It will continue to run each block even if an exception is raised. We want it to stop running if any other exception occurs except "-942 table does not exist."  If the table does not exist, the rest of the procedure should continue to run, all others should cause it to stop.  How can I do this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PURGE_RECORDS

(vCLIENT_ID IN VARCHAR2, pINPUTSCOPE IN VARCHAR2,
  pSUCCESS_IND OUT VARCHAR2, pOUTCOME_DESC OUT VARCHAR2)

AS

  VTABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(200);  
  vSQL VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN

  IF pINPUTSCOPE = 'ALL' THEN

    BEGIN
      VTABLE_NAME := 'TABLE NAME';
      vSQL := ' 
          DELETE FROM TABLENAME T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 TSK WHERE CLIENT = '''|| vCLIENT_ID ||''' AND ASK_ID = T.ASK_ID)   ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
    END;

    BEGIN
      VTABLE_NAME := 'TABLE NAME';
      vSQL := ' 
          DELETE FROM TABLENAME3 T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 TSK WHERE CLIENT = '''|| vCLIENT_ID ||''' AND ASK_ID = T.ASK_ID)  ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
    END;

    BEGIN
      VTABLE_NAME := 'TABLE NAME';
      vSQL := ' 
          DELETE FROM TABLENAME4 T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE4 TSK WHERE CLIENT = '''|| vCLIENT_ID ||''' AND ASK_ID = T.ASK_ID)  ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
    END;

    BEGIN
      VTABLE_NAME := 'TABLE NAME';
      vSQL := ' 
          DELETE FROM TABLENAME5 T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE5 TSK WHERE CLIENT = '''|| vCLIENT_ID ||''' AND ASK_ID = T.ASK_ID)  ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
    END;
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Do you think you could format this question a little better? It's hard to read in its current state.

Comment: Sure.  I hope this is better.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You should use at least 4 spaces to indent all code.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections to my question.  Very new to this.... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly catch the ORA-00942 error, report it you want to, and then ignore it; and then either handle all other exceptions with a RAISE - which will propagate the exception to the next block, in this case causing the procedure to terminate - or don't catch them at all.

ORA-00942 isn't one of [the predefined exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00703) so you need to define an exception name and use [the `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exceptioninit_pragma.htm) to associate the exception to [the internally defined exception number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS99871):

```
...
AS
  VTABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(200);  
  vSQL VARCHAR2(10000);

  NO_SUCH_TABLE EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (NO_SUCH_TABLE, -942);
BEGIN

  IF pINPUTSCOPE = 'ALL' THEN

    BEGIN
      VTABLE_NAME := 'TABLE NAME';
      vSQL := ' 
          DELETE FROM TABLENAME T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 TSK WHERE CLIENT = '''|| vCLIENT_ID ||''' AND ASK_ID = T.ASK_ID)   ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_SUCH_TABLE THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
          -- this exception has been squashed
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
          RAISE;
    END;
    ...
```

And repeat the exception catch in each sub-block. Any other exception will still be caught by your `OTHERS` handler. Catching and squashing `OTHERS` is generally a bad idea, and it would be better to remove that and let the exceptions propagate naturally; even though you're displaying the error (assuming whoever runs this is showing the output), you're losing the line number of the original problem. So you only really need to do:

```
...
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (  VTABLE_NAME || '  Scope set: ' ||  pINPUTSCOPE || ' ' || '(' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' ROWS DELETED)' || chr(10));
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_SUCH_TABLE THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR :  ' || VTABLE_NAME || ' ' ||  SQLERRM);
          -- this exception has been squashed, all others will propagate
    END;

    ...
```